# Set Iframe src with string html variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have a function that receives a parameter html string query, I would like to set this parameter as source of the Iframe something like this `src : @Html.Raw(result)` to then display on the view. Is there a way to do it?

View

```
<div id="DisplayHTML"></div>
```

Function

```
function GetValues(result) {
           $("#DisplayHTML").html(
               $('<iframe>', {
                   src:// Here is where I would like to add the result parameter,
                        width: '600px',
                        height: "800px"
                    })
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the src attribute of an iframe with an HTML string variable in JavaScript, you can use the data URI scheme. Example:

```js
function GetValues(result) {
  $("#DisplayHTML").html(
    $('<iframe>', {
      src: 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(result),
      width: '600px',
      height: '800px'
    })
  );
}
```

The encodeURIComponent function is used to properly encode the HTML string so that it can be used within the data URI. The result parameter is appended to the data URI by prefixing it with 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,'.

[encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Thank you it works do you if I want to display PDF how should be the src data?